# Can Kung fu fighters fight with weapons in international tournaments?

Tags: kung-fu, weapons, competition

In Kung fu fighting sometimes fighters use lethal weapons. Sometimes two fighters fight and sometimes a group of fighters fight. Can Kung fu fighters fight with weapons in international tournaments?

Answer (score 1):

In almost all kung-fu tournaments, weapons are not used in sparring competition. Instead, competitors demonstrate their skill in various weapons through the performance of forms (taolu).

Forms are routines, like dance choreography, that get performed by the competitor. These forms may be traditional or contemporary. Traditional forms generally emphasize practical fighting skills. Contemporary forms generally emphasize performance. Each type has technical qualities that the judges are looking for. Competitors all aspire to excellence.

The IWUF has a web site that goes over all the details about what the judges look for, and how it is scored:

http://www.iwuf.org/sport-wushu/taolu/

There are plenty of IWUF videos there and on Youtube to look at. They show how each technique should be done. And they show entire forms there as well.

As for sparring with weapons, kung-fu styles almost always forbid it and only engage in "two-man sets" which involve two people performing predetermined movements against each other. With two-man sets, there's still some risk involved, but they go slow until they can reliably avoid getting hurt.

Only on occasion have I found kung-fu groups which do practice sparring with weapons, but they will use padded weapons, armor, protective masks and goggles, etc. A sword is roughly approximated as a padded stick, for example. When they do this, the sparring generally doesn't look like the movies or even much like kung-fu. But it's very useful, nonetheless. And there are tournaments (though rare) that do involve these kinds of weapons sparring. I have not seen them at the international level, so this would be in local / regional tournaments only.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In fact I used to participate in Kung fu fighting in China.That is all about my experience about Kung fu fighting.User 37920

Comment: Weigan Famous kung fu fighter BRUCE LEE died in street fighting, but that was not a tournament.I guess this is a single case. other death cases in Kung fu fighting in streets are perhaps not reported. user 37920

Comment: But a few years back a report came out BRUCE LEE died of various illnesses and drinking a drink. user-37920

Comment: Evidence still points to cerebral edema for Bruce Lee's death. He'd had an episode two months before, and the painkiller he took can cause that sort of a reaction.